# Angular 4 ngFor variable not visible inside certain sub component

Tags: angular, angular2-template, ngfor

I've got a really strange issue going on.  I'm using a simple ngFor loop in my template code and while the variable is visible almost anywhere inside the loop, there's one subcomponent that it doesn't seem to penetrate for some reason.  Wondering if anyone has any insight.  When inside of my bb-card-image component, the module.icon variable isn't available, but outside of it and even inside the bb-card-content, I'm able to access everything.

```html
<md-grid-tile *ngFor="let module of dash_modules">
    <bb-card *ngIf="_auth.can( module.id, 'read' )" [routerLink]="module.link">
        <md-icon color="accent">{{ module.icon }}</md-icon> <~~~~ This one works.
        <bb-card-image>
            <md-icon color="accent">{{ module.icon }}</md-icon> <~~~~ This module.icon does not work.
        </bb-card-image>
        <bb-card-content>
            <h3 class="center" translate>{{ module.name }}</h3> <~~~~~ This works fine as well even though its within a subcomponent
            <p class="center" translate>
                {{ module.desc }}  <~~~~ Works as well
            </p>
        </bb-card-content>
    </bb-card>
</md-grid-tile>
```

Comment: Why do you have `[icon]="module.icon"` there? An `md-icon` should be set either by `svgIcon` or by ligature. You have the ligature set already, so remove the property binding.

Comment: My apologies, I was testing to see if the module.icon would render there and it made it into this clipping.  I'll remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured out what was going on.  Inside my bb-card-image component, I was dynamically adding shadows and certain things for styles.  It turns out that by modifying the innerHTML of the container that holds that md-icon, it somehow lost the value inside the tag.  I'm still not sure how that's possible since I was just doing this in the code:

```js
img_elem.querySelector( ".card-image" ).innerHTML += `
    <div class="colored-shadow" style="opacity: 1;"></div>
    <div class="ripple-container"></div>
`;
```